# What are all the small transactions in Satoshi's address?

Tags: genesis-block, satoshi-nakamoto

I read that Satoshi never moved or spent his coins, so I expected to see his address stay unchanged since mined. But it looks like there are lots of small transactions: e.g. in [the first address](https://blockchain.info/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa) there are more than 1000 txs, and in [the second address](https://blockchain.info/address/12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX), there are about 65. What are those for? Who made them and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, because Bitcoin is (mostly) anonymous, we can't know for sure who has been sending these, let alone their reasons.  But some guesses:

- People donating money to Satoshi, since it's known to be his address.
- Mistakes.  Satoshi's address is commonly used as an example in guides for creating transactions, etc, and it could be that some people copied the example and forgot to change the destination address.
- Attention.  I saw some transactions with attached OP_RETURN messages, e.g. [this one](https://blockchain.info/tx/776ece649515098d56bbc60ef497e3bfe5400b7aeeda9711fcf1a4fdfac2f337) (see under "Output Scripts" near the bottom).  By sending to a well-known address, there is a better chance that curious people like you will stumble upon the transaction and read the message.
- Just for lols.
- There are altcoins and other protocols that rely on "burning" bitcoins by sending them to a well-known address with no known private key.  A variant on this would be to send the coins to Satoshi.  Either he eventually spends them (so it becomes a donation) or he doesn't (so it's a burn), but either way the parties involved probably aren't getting the coins back.  I haven't seen this variant in practice but it's conceivable that someone has tried it.