# Why do many of the early bitcoin addresses receive small transactions many years later?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, address, dust

For example...

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/addresses/btc/1NHHWnZKTetjZZfAbVjTS9EHQafdH6xn8a

...receives a block reward of 50 BTC in 2009 and then transactions in 2019, 2020, 2021 for tiny amounts.

Actually if you look through the first few hundred blocks it's extremely common to see these early addresses receiving small amounts of sats in recent years.  Is someone doing this for nostalgia's sake or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70303/what-are-all-the-small-transactions-in-satoshis-address

Comment: yes it does, thanks @sutterseba!